# grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory

Tags: error-handling

I am using a Mac computer and I get this message when running  `mirdeep2 mapper.pl` script:

```
grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the script author say that the script supports Mac?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Does macOS have a command to retrieve detailed CPU information like /proc/cpuinfo on Linux?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352769/does-macos-have-a-command-to-retrieve-detailed-cpu-information-like-proc-cpuinf)

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

It appears as though you can safely ignore the error.

The code has numerous fail-overs to do what it's doing in a robust way.

(In mapper.pl):

```perl
## check number of cores on the system and threads to be used
my $cores=`grep -ic ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`;
if($cores !~ /^\d+$/){
    $cores=`sysctl -n hw.physicalcpu`;
    if($cores !~ /^\d+$/){
        $cores=`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu`;
    }
}
if($cores !~ /^\d+$/){
    $cores=1;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/rajewsky-lab/mirdeep2/blob/c7405efa265ad43c4366b65547dcd622e80c2f63/src/mapper.pl#L145-L154

### Longer Answer

I guess if you really wanted to silence the errors, you could open up `mapper.pl` and replace:

```perl
my $cores=`grep -ic ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`;
```

with

```perl
my $cores=`grep -ic ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null`;
```

or even

```perl
my $cores=`nproc`;
```

Comment: I changed the mapper.pl file as suggested by doing replacement using one of  two options separately. It did not map. here are results:#desc total mapped unmapped %mapped %unmapped
total: 378333 0 378333 0.000 100.000
seq: 378333 0 378333 0.000 100.000

Comment: Is there any other suggestion?